# 'PRIME Profiles' tab missing in NVIDIA X Server Settings (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, gpu, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

I have nvidia-settings and nvidia-prime installed, but the 'PRIME Profiles' tab is missing.

How can I fix it to be able to switch between my GPUs?

**Update:**

```
~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GK208M [GeForce GT 740M]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

[image: My Drivers]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Question updated.

Comment: You did not install Nvidia drivers, that is why PRIME does not work. Obvious.

Comment: Switched to Nvidia drivers and restarted... the tab finally appeared after the second 'cycle' of reinstalling PRIME + switching between drivers + rebooting. Not sure why it didn't the very first time, as I'm absolutely sure that I had Nvidia drivers running at the time.
+ Not sure if the things are connected, but after my first reboot with 'PRIME Profiles' tab present, logging in took longer and a message about an internal error appeared. (ExecutablePath: `/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon`). When I rebooted again to check if it's a constant issue, I had no such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `nvidia-361` in terminal or in GUI, reboot, and PRIME will appear.

It works only with NVIDIA proprietary drivers.

Comment: See a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207084/prime-profiles-tab-missing-in-nvidia-settings-ubuntu-18-04-geforce-mx150-nv), for a slightly different case, with `nvidia-driver-440` installed, not yet solved.