# Ubuntu 16.04 not working after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

Hello fellow users of Ubuntu some days ago I tried to configure an Nvidia Prime profile since my PC was only using Intel and wasn't powerful enough.

I only typed one command wich I can barely remember and then had to shutdown my PC since I had other things to do. Command, which is the following:

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-361

[EDIT] : I might have followed this guide : ['PRIME Profiles' tab missing in NVIDIA X Server Settings (Ubuntu 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805199/prime-profiles-tab-missing-in-nvidia-x-server-settings-ubuntu-16-04)

Today I booted up my PC and everything started good, but after the purple Ubuntu screen with the dots it doesn't show anything!

That's is my problem thanks for helping me! ^^

P.S.: My graphic card is an Nvidia GeForce 940MX with 2GB dedicated ram.

Comment: The only driver version supporting such ancient chipset is the current LTS 340.

Comment: So what do I have to do? I tried to purge nvidia-361 and now Ubuntu is running in low graphics mode!

Comment: By the way how to you know which chipset is supported by which driver? Is 340 the latest I can get?

Comment: I know by checking nvidia.com or geforce,com. That's what you should do before installing (don't download and install Nvidia binaries but do check supported versions) and yes, 340 is the only one you can use now for all the still supported legacy hardware.

Comment: Okay, but what do I do a bout the low graphic mode?

Comment: Reinstall 340?...

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Purge the previous installation, install 340? Sorry, I don't understand. You indicated you know how to install (and purge, apparently) the drivers, you were just using the wrong version.