# "PRIME Profiles" tab missing in nvidia-settings (Ubuntu 18.04, GeForce Mx150, nvidia-driver-440)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

**How do I get [*PRIME profiles*] tab show up in `nvidia-settings`?**

The situation is similar to the one described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805199/prime-profiles-tab-missing-in-nvidia-x-server-settings-ubuntu-16-04), but this is on Ubuntu 18.04, and the nvidia driver *is* installed. Still nvidia-settings gives a **CRITICAL** error message in the console:

```
(nvidia-settings:3290): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:03:31.871: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
GPU at BusId 0x1 doesn't have a supported video decoder
```

See `lspci` and `apt-list` outputs:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP108M [GeForce MX150]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

**Actual nvidia packages** installed:

```
$ sudo apt list nvidia* | grep install
nvidia-compute-utils-440/sconosciuto,now 440.33.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-dkms-440/sconosciuto,now 440.33.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-driver-440/sconosciuto,now 440.33.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installato]
nvidia-kernel-common-440/sconosciuto,now 440.33.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-kernel-source-440/sconosciuto,now 440.33.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-prime/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 0.8.8.2 all [installato, automatico]
nvidia-settings/sconosciuto,now 440.33.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
nvidia-utils-440/sconosciuto,now 440.33.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installato, automatico]
```

Should I install another driver? Should it be installed in addition or as a replacement?

Answer (score 3):

You likely have an issue with conflicting driver packages from multiple repositories. This can be tricky if you are using CUDA.

Open a terminal like konsole and then select the desired GPU as shown below. Use nvidia for high performance or intel for increased battery life.

```bsh
sudo su -
prime-select query  # show options
prime-select nvidia # select nvidia gpu
prime-select intel  # select intel gpu
reboot
```

One should reboot immediately after switching graphics to avoid artifacts and glitches.