# "PRIME Profiles" tab missing in nvidia-settings (Ubuntu 22.04, GeForce RTX 3080, nvidia-driver-525 (525.105.17))

Tags: 22.04, gpu, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

I already saw similar posts, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207084/prime-profiles-tab-missing-in-nvidia-settings-ubuntu-18-04-geforce-mx150-nv) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805199/prime-profiles-tab-missing-in-nvidia-x-server-settings-ubuntu-16-04).

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 (using Xorg).

I have a GeForce RTX 3080.

```
> nvidia-smi 
Sun Apr 30 09:33:25 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.105.17   Driver Version: 525.105.17   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   43C    P8    31W / 340W |    507MiB / 10240MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2393      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                114MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2600    C+G   ...ome-remote-desktop-daemon      217MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2639      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               37MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4275      G   ...9/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      132MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
> sudo prime-select query
on-demand
```

```
> /usr/bin/nvidia-settings

(nvidia-settings:39496): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:43:42.816: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 09:43:42.914: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 09:43:42.914: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

[image]

I know I could switch between modes like this:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia # select nvidia gpu
sudo prime-select intel  # select intel gpu
```

But I would like to know why I can't see anymore PRIME profile tab in the nvidia-settings GUI application. I already tried different driver versions but each one of those just seems to bring me issues in the functioning (also hangs on boot sometimes). The right drivers for my GPU seems to be the 525 version.

EDIT - 1

I just tried @ThomZen answer.
This is what was my nvidia-settings situation:

```
> apt policy nvidia-settings
nvidia-settings:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 510.47.03-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     510.47.03-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

And...

```
> nvidia-settings -v

nvidia-settings:  version 530.30.02
```

So I tried to remove my current version (530.30.02) and install the 510.47.03 version:

```
> sudo apt remove nvidia-settings
> sudo apt install nvidia-settings=510.47.03-0ubuntu1
> nvidia-settings -v

nvidia-settings:  version 510.47.03
```

But still PRIME profiles tab is missing in the GUI app:
[image]

Comment: Same here, I have RTX 4050 Laptop. I was having screen frequncy issue first, then it's solved somehow and now I can't see any Prime tab and plus, when I put the laptop on sleep gpu doesn't go to sleep and its burning up on my backpack :\

Answer (score 1):

Hi to all with similar problem!
Same issue here on Ubuntu Studio 22.04. 
Be aware: I found a solution but it is somewhat pointless as older drivers (that you are going to install) just activate the "Performance Mode" if you choose "on-demand". At least a little popup tells you that if you choose this option via X-Server GUI.
Nevertheless:
After installing CUDA drivers the option “Prime Profiles” was not available / not showing. The only solution that helped me was given in [this discussion](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/latest-nvidia-update-causes-issues-with-the-prime-profile/229427/4):

List all nvidia versions available in the repositories you have added with

```
apt policy nvidia-settings
```

Then install the one that was shipped with your ubuntu version with command

```
sudo apt install nvidia-settings=VERSION_FROM_UBUNTU
```

As I wrote it will bring back the option "on-demand" to your GUI but it is rather senseless.

Have nice day!

Comment: I just tried this, but it does not seem to work for me. See my EDIT details on original question.